# How to replace the control style under mouseover according to custom conditions in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a richtextbox control here. I want to base on the x property (string type) of a custom class. When it is a different value, the style of the richtextbox control under MouseOver is different. I want to know how to realize this idea.

I've tried styleselector, but I don't know where to apply them. I also tried a multi-condition trigger, but the property x of the custom class I don't know how to be treated as a condition. So, which idea is feasible, the styleselector? Multiple conditional triggers? Or a template selector? Thank you all.

Comment: The visual appearance of elements is determined by their template.
The default styles (including the template) are set by the theme. In Win10 themes, the visual appearance of an element in non-normal states is defined by constants. These constants set the color of the text, background, and frame. If you need to change any of these parameters, you will have to create your own custom template. If something else, then you can limit yourself to your style. Therefore, describe in more detail what and how exactly you want to change depending on the value of the data property.

Comment: Oh the irony of: "It would be better to have a specific code reference or a detailed description".

You should describe your requirements better. If you want code to illustrate a solution then don't make people have to invent everything for you.  It is very easy to misunderstand a question like this and then find you wasted time. As a result, experienced contributors will likely be reluctant to invest more time than someone has invested in posting a question.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, that sentence caused your dissatisfaction. I have been thinking about this question for several days. It is because I can’t think of an effective code, so I thought of asking for ideas here. I am very sorry if I offend you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.